# How to pass data from Activity to fragment using OnFragmentInteractionListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have Main activity and it have 3 fragments inside tab layout. i have to call api from activity and pass data to all three fragments after successfull response. After data passed i have to show data inside fragment. How it can be done through `OnFragmentInteractionListener`?

**Default created fragment**

```
class StudentDetails : Fragment() {

private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {

    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student_details, container, false)

    return view
}


override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        listener = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
    }
}



interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    fun onFragmentInteraction(name:String,phone:String){
    }
}

companion object {

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() =
        StudentDetails().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {

            }
        }
}
}
```

**Activity**

```
class StudentDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity(),StudentDetails.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_detail)
      .....

      setupViewPager()
    }

    private fun setupViewPager(){
    val adapter = StudentDetailsViewPager(supportFragmentManager)

    val firstFragment : StudentDetails = StudentDetails.newInstance()
    val secondFragment : StudentDetails = StudentDetails.newInstance()
    val thirdFragment : StudentDetails = StudentDetails.newInstance()

    adapter.addFragment(firstFragment,"Student")
    adapter.addFragment(secondFragment,"Class")
    adapter.addFragment(thirdFragment,"Fees")

    val viewPager = view_pager

    viewPager.adapter = adapter
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
}

     private fun getStudentDetails(student_id : String?){
    val inst_id = SharedPreferenceManager(this).getInstituteId()
    RetrofitClientCommon.client.create(StudentApi::class.java).getStudentDetails(student_id!!,inst_id!!).enqueue(object : Callback<com.digimkey.digimke.Institute.models.StudentDetails>{
        override fun onFailure(
            call: Call<com.digimkey.digimke.Institute.models.StudentDetails>,
            t: Throwable
        ) {
            Toast.makeText(this@StudentDetailActivity,t.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<com.digimkey.digimke.Institute.models.StudentDetails>,
            response: Response<com.digimkey.digimke.Institute.models.StudentDetails>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                val res = response.body() as com.digimkey.digimke.Institute.models.StudentDetails
                val phone = res.phone

                onFragmentInteraction(name,phone!!)
            }else{
                val error = response.errorBody()!!.string()
                Toast.makeText(this@StudentDetailActivity,error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    })
}

override fun onFragmentInteraction(name:String,phone:String) {

}
}
```

Comment: https://androidwave.com/fragment-communication-using-viewmodel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Main Activity**

```
class StudentDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity(),StudentDetails.OnFragmentInteractionListener {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_detail)

     ..............
    setupViewPager(id)
}

private fun setupViewPager(id:String?){
    val adapter = StudentDetailsViewPager(supportFragmentManager)

    val firstFragment : StudentDetails = StudentDetails.newInstance()
    val secondFragment : StudentDetails = StudentDetails.newInstance()
    val thirdFragment : StudentDetails = StudentDetails.newInstance()

    adapter.addFragment(firstFragment,"Student")
    adapter.addFragment(secondFragment,"Class")
    adapter.addFragment(thirdFragment,"Fees")

    val viewPager = view_pager

    viewPager.adapter = adapter
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    getStudentDetails(id,firstFragment)
}

private fun getStudentDetails(student_id : String?,fragmentOne:StudentDetails){
    val inst_id = SharedPreferenceManager(this).getInstituteId()
    RetrofitClientCommon.client.create(StudentApi::class.java).getStudentDetails(student_id!!,inst_id!!).enqueue(object : Callback<com.digimkey.digimke.Institute.models.StudentDetails>{
        override fun onFailure(
            call: Call<com.digimkey.digimke.Institute.models.StudentDetails>,
            t: Throwable
        ) {
            Toast.makeText(this@StudentDetailActivity,t.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<com.digimkey.digimke.Institute.models.StudentDetails>,
            response: Response<com.digimkey.digimke.Institute.models.StudentDetails>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                val res = response.body() as com.digimkey.digimke.Institute.models.StudentDetails
                val name = res.first_name
                val phone = res.phone

                fragmentOne.updateData(name,phone!!)

            }else{
                val error = response.errorBody()!!.string()
                Toast.makeText(this@StudentDetailActivity,error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    })
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class StudentDetails : Fragment() {

private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null
private lateinit var txtName : TextView
private lateinit var txtPhone : TextView

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student_details, container, false)

    txtName = view.txtName
    txtPhone = view.txtMobile

    return view
}

fun updateData(name: String,phone: String){
    txtName.text = name
    txtPhone.text = phone
}

companion object {

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() =
        StudentDetails().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {

            }
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

great question.

Honestly I feel the onFragmentinteraction is an outdated ugly way of communicating. If you want an honest opinion there are two much better ways to communicate. Since you are communicating with 3 fragments, I promise you if you get a nice MVVM going with observables, you will celebrate and thank yourself lol, but let's go through both options so you can decide for yourself :).

1) ViewModel - following modern day MVVM patterns.

In your Activity you simply have the ViewModel of your choice like so:

```
class MySpecialViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
      val someChangingVar = MutableLiveData<String>() //typically private and exposed through method

      fun setSomeChangingVar(value: newString) {
           someChangingVar.value = newString //triggers observers
      }
}

class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {  
    //create instance of MySpecialViewModel owned by My Lifecycle   
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MySpecialViewModel>()

    override onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        observeSomeChangingVar()
    }

    fun someButtonClicked() {
        viewModel.setSomeChangingVar("Hi") //triggers obsever in fragment and self
    }

    fun observeSomeChangingVar() {
       viewModel.someChangingVar.observe(this, Observer { newValue->
            Log.v("tag", newValue) //could have been set from fragment
       })
    }
}

class MyChildFragment : Fragment() {
     //creates or retrieves (if already exists) an instance of MySpecialViewModel owned by MyActivity Lifecycle (keyword "activityViewModels" rather then "viewModels" 
     //Note it will exist because it was created in activity already, think of this like a hashmap of viewModels in memory
     private val viewModel by activityViewModels<MySpecialViewModel>()

     override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
          super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
          observeSomeChangingVar()
     }

     fun observeSomeChangingVar() {
        viewModel.someChangingVar.observe(this, Observer { newValue->
            Log.v("tag", newValue) //could have been set from fragment
        })
     }

     fun someButtonClicked() {
          viewModel.setSomeChangingVar("Hi") //triggers obsever in activity and self
     }
}
```

> using "viewModels" will create a viewModel of that
>   class who's lifescope is tied to the the class that it's in (in the
>   case of MyActivity it's the Activity that owns the viewModel life
>   scope in the hashmap, NOTE* I'm using hashmap to help the concept sink in, not specifying how it is actually managed under the hood".

**LET'S SEE THE CODE**

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {    
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MySpecialViewModel>()
```

> Above we have an instance of MySpecialViewModel owned by MyActivity

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {    
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MySpecialViewModel>()
```

> Above we have an instance of MySpecialViewModel owned by Fragment.
>   Entirely different instance of the viewModel, not at all coupled with
>   activity ViewModel

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {    
    private val viewModel by activityViewModels<MySpecialViewModel>()
```

> Above we have an instance of MySpecialViewModel owned by
>   parentActivity. If it already existed, which in our case it did, it
>   will retrieve the current one from memory rather then creating a new
>   one. If it didn't exist, it would create one with the lifecycle tied
>   to the activity and could still be shared among other fragments even
>   if the activity doesn't have an instance of it inside itself.

Our objective for communicating is to have the same instance of viewModel in each fragment that needs to talk with the activity's data. So we will want to ensure we use the same instance to be returned to both the activity and the fragment. You see how this is done above already.

Like I said before, think of it like a hashmap where the keys are the owner of the instance of the active viewModels. you can pass your fragment as the key and find null and thus create a new one or you can pass the activity as the key and find the existing one to use or if null, it will create one with the activity as the key.

**Now in case you really don't want to use viewModels for sharing data and you have a specific use case where you need to call methods of the fragment or activity you can simply use interfaces and/or base classes. Yes I understand there are a dozens ways to skin this cat, so please take my desired approach as my preference and not necessarily the best way in existence :)**

I'll provide an example for both:

2)

**INTERACTING WITH ACTIVITY FROM FRAGMENT USING INTERFACES**

```
interface IParentActivityCallback {
    fun HeyActivityDoSomethingForMe(value: String)
}

class ParentActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IParentActivityCallback {
    override heyActivityDoSomethingForMe(value: String) {
         Log.v("tag", "Ok fragment, I'll do what you said")
    }
}

class fragment: Fragment() {
    var myParentActivityCallback: IParentActivityCallback? = null

    override onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try {
            myParentActivityCallback = context as IParentActivityCallback
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            //welp, you screwed up :P
        }
    }
    fun someButtonClicked() {
        myParentActivityCallback?.heyActivityDoSomethingForMe("Hi")
    }
}
```

**INTERACTING WITH FRAGMENT FROM ACTIVITY USING BASECLASS OR INTERFACE**

```
abstract open class BaseFragment: Fragment() {
     abstract fun heyFragmentDoSomethingForMe(value: String)
}

class MyChildFragment: BaseFragment() {
     override heyFragmentDoSomethingForMe(value: String) {
         Log.v("tag", "Ok activity, I'll do what you said")
     }
}

class ParentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var selectedFragment: BaseFragment? = null

    fun placeVisibleFragment(someFragment: Fragment) {
        selectedFragment = someFragment
        //transaction put fragment in place
    }

    fun parentButtonClicked() { 
        selectedFragment?.heyFragmentDoSomethingForMe("Hi")
    }
}
```

Of course this can be done with an interface as well if preferred, you don't have to do it with a base class, just depends on your need and desired architecture.

**GIVE ME A REAL WORLD EXAMPLE PLEASE**

> Ok, no problem. If you aren't using the navigation framework yet, due
>   to all it's annoying bugs and toolbar issues lol. I often found myself
>   doing this for passing through certain activity behaviors to the
>   fragment. For example getting onBackPressed to the child before handling in the activity or getting the title to show from the fragment:

**SHOW ME THE CODE**

```
abstract open class BaseFragment: Fragment() {
     abstract fun onBackPressed(): Boolean
     abstract fun getTitleResourceId(): Int
}

class MyChildFragment: BaseFragment() {
     override onBackPressed(): Boolean {
         return didIHandleBackPressDownHere()
     }
     override getTitleResourceId() = R.string.myFragmentTitle
}


class ParentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var selectedFragment: BaseFragment? = null

    fun placeVisibleFragment(someFragment: Fragment) {
        selectedFragment = someFragment
        toolbarTitle.set(getString(selectedFragment?.getTitleResourceId?: R.string.general_title))
        //transaction put fragment in place
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() { 
        if(selectedFragment?.onBackPressed() == false) {
             super.onBackPressed() //only handle if child returns false
        }
    }
}
```

> Hope that adds some clarity on communicating different ways. The
>   onFragmentListener is just passing ugly URL string schemas back and
>   forth and is ugly to maintain and ugly to use. So do yourself a favor
>   and use good architecture instead of the free boilerplate method that
>   Android Studio creates when you add a fragment.

Happy Coding

Comment: Awsm answer with an explanation.  Appreciate :)

Comment: no problem Ajay, if it was the answer you are looking for, don't forget to mark it as the correct one so that it shows answered.

Comment: what are **activityViewModels** and **viewModels** ?

Comment: @OmarBoshra when you want to lazy load (or create when used first time) you use the viewModels<typeOfViewModel>() call as a variable. this assigns the viewModel that you created to a local variable owned by the current class scope. If you are in a fragment or dialog fragment it also does this. However, if you want several fragments to share a viewModel you can let the activity be the owner of the viewModel by using activityViewModel<TypeOfViewModel>() this will create a shared instance in each fragment that declares it and that variable will be scoped as a singleton in the activity basically.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#Deliver). In general you need the following:

1. Create a public method in each fragment for consuming the data
2. Find each fragment by **supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById()** in your Activity.
3. Pass the data from your Activity to the Fragment by using the public methods defined in step 1.

Comment: How to get id of fragment? It's a tab layout fragment.

Comment: @AjayGohel as far as I can see, I could not find this info in your question. You should mention in your question that you are dealing with a tab layout. Please, give more info - is the number of tabs dynamic? / share your ViewPager code.

Comment: If the number of tabs is static and you know the exact type and ordering of the fragments in the viewpager adapter, you can use something like viewPagerAdapter.getFragment(fragmentPosition).setYourCustomData(customData)

Comment: I have posted answer with public method as u said in your answer. Its working fine. Pls tell me its a good practice to update data like thta?

Comment: Looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is much easier using the ViewModel.

1. Create ViewModel
2. Declare in the ViewModel an object including the information you want to share between fragments.
3. In every fragment add an observer to watch any changes in the value of the object you declared before. There you will have a listener where you can do whatever you need when the value is changed.
4. Make sure you initialize the value of the observed object on onCreate() in the activity.

In this way is very easy to keep track of the changes and react to them.
For the exact piece of code required, create a Tabbed Activity using the wizard and you will see an example where a ViewModel is created, how to initilize the ViewModel is demostrated and an example of an observer can be found.